# Cannon Fire Phaser3

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I want to make cannon fire for my game I developed in 2D phaser3. I haven't achieved this move yet.
When I code it this way, it falls directly down sharply after a certain point. How can I get the Cannon Fire shot here.

```
import {
  ActorProps,
  ICollectable,
  IDieable,
  IMoveable,
} from "@games/common/interfaces";
import { Actor } from "@games/common/objects";

export default class Cannon
  extends Actor
  implements IMoveable, IDieable, ICollectable
{
  declare body: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body;

  private initialX: number;
  private initialY: number;
  private velocityX: number;
  private velocityY: number;
  private isMoving: boolean;
  private isMovingUp: boolean;

  constructor(props: ActorProps) {
    super(props);
    this.scene.physics.add.existing(this);
    this.body.setAllowGravity(false);

    this.initialX = this.x;
    this.initialY = this.y;
    this.velocityX = 100;
    this.velocityY = -100;
    this.isMoving = true;
    this.isMovingUp = true;
  }

  update(time: number, delta: number): void {
    if (this.isMoving) {
      this.x -= this.velocityX * (delta / 1000);
      this.y += this.velocityY * (delta / 2000) * 0.5;

      if (this.x >= this.initialX + 200 || this.y <= this.initialY - 200) {
        this.velocityY = -this.velocityY;
      }

      if (this.velocityY < 0 && this.y >= this.initialY) {
        this.isMoving = false;
        this.y = this.initialY;
      }
    }
  }

  die(): void {}

  move(): void {}

  collect(...props: any[]): void {}
}
```

Currently the object is accelerating up and to the left from the starting position, but I cannot get the result I want because it moves according to fixed values.

I made this code in unity and it works correctly. I used the parabola formula.

```
public float a=-1, b=0, c=0;
    
    public float x=-5;
    [Range(0,10)]public float speed;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(x,axx+bx+c,0);
        transform.position = newPos;
        x += Time.deltaTime speed;
    }
```

Comment: I wnated to know if my answer solved your question, if so please consider accepting it with the greencheckmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is, that you are **not** using the phyiscs engine.
you **shouldn't** set `x` and `y` properties yourself, you should let the engine do this for you. With the function `setVelocity` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Components.Velocity.html#setVelocity__anchor)), or set the acceleration with `setAcceleration` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setAcceleration__anchor)).

But to use those functions you woould have to rewrite some of your code.

> Checkout these offical examples/demos *([basic platformer](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics/arcade/basic%20platform.js&v=3.60.0), [mini spaceship](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics/arcade/asteroids%20movement.js&v=3.60.0), [acrade physics example collectio](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/physics/arcade)n )* for details how to use the arcade engine in phaser.